# MYSQL to android data transfers

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I would like to transfer mysql data to the android phone and vice versa.

So far i got the .php file down to bring up the information i need but I cant get a code that would take the page's code and convert it into a string or integer in android.

I'm currently using this code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class version extends ListActivity {
JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
//convert response to string
try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
       sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
       String line="0";
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
//paring data
String version;
try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      JSONObject json_data=null;
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             version=json_data.getString("versioncode");
         }
      }
      catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error in getting version code. Please report." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

How do I get it so it'll compare the current application version to the string i provided in the mysql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close, I would do this:

```
if (version.equals("1.0.2") {
  // same version
else {
  // different version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I  tried your code, it worked for me.
Use "Activity" in place of "ListActivity".

And make sure you have given permission "android.permission.INTERNET" in manifest.xml file.